# OpenVPN Speed Slow

Tags: vpn, openvpn

**Background:**

I have an OpenVPN server running on my Netgear R7000 [openddwrt] router. My ISP connection is 50 mb/s down and 25 mb/s up. When connecting to my vpn from my cellphone, and windows computer I never get any higher than 1.8 mb/s down, and sometimes I can get 3-4 mp/s up. I tested the speed on my phone I get over 8 mb/s down. The CPU is averaging at 4-10%

**What I have tried:**

- Changing from AES-256-CBC to BF-CBC
- Removing compression
- Setting it to UDP
- Setting the sndbuf 0 and rcvbuf 0
- Changing MTU-TUN to 1500

**Question:**
All changes have done nothing to the speed. Is there anything I can do to improve my speed?

**Config:**

```
#Route internet
push "route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "redirect-gateway def1"
keepalive 10 60
sndbuf 0
rcvbuf 0
verb 5
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with the server on your router and not the clients? the transfer rates need to be supported on both ends of the tunnel.

Comment: I am not sure where the problem lies. Do you have a suggestions as to what I can try next?

Comment: The link transfer rate is going to be the lowest speed of either end. It's certainly possible that your cell phone, or a computer on a remote network, just can't transfer data over a VPN any faster than what you see on your router's VPN server.

Comment: Okay, so is there a way to check this speed and find out where it maxes out?

Comment: You need a computer on a network with a normally very fast transfer rate to connect as a client to your VPN. I don't see why that matters if your cell phone and PC can't do any faster with the circumstance under which you will use them. If you learn that your VPN server can do much faster transfers, but you can't use that, why would that even matter to you?

Comment: Just to cover my bases.